# const reference data member bound to a temporary initializing that reference in a constructor

Tags: c++

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {
    const char *name;

    A() : name("A") {
        std::cout << "A()\n";
    }

    virtual ~A() {
        std::cout << "~A()\n";
    }
};

class B {
    const A& a;
public:

    B() : a(A()) {
    };

    void print_data() const {
        std::cout << a.name << '\n';
    }

    ~B() {
        std::cout << "~B()\n";
    }
};

int main() {
    B b;
    b.print_data();
    return 0;
}
```

The output from GCC 4.4 is:

> A()  ~A()  A ~B()

This looks strange to me. I would have expected either a copy of the temporary instance of A being bound to the B::a or that temporary itself being destructed during ~B().

Basically, I thought B::a is always a valid reference during the life of b. In fact b.print_data() works apparently and the compiler does not give any warning.

What does the standard c++98/03 say about this matter?

Comment: I never understood which is the main target of such kind of questions. You just can read the c++ reference. Also how often do you use this structure in real projects?

Comment: Hopefully NEVER!  lol - that would be a broken design. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Constant references don't prolong the life of temporaries in classes, period. It's just like that. They only do it in `Foo const& f = Foo();` where `foo` returns by-value, but that's it.

`§12.2 [class.temporary]`

> p4 There are two contexts in which temporaries are destroyed at a different point than the end of the full expression. [...]
>
> p5 The second context is when a reference is bound to a temporary. The temporary to which the reference is bound or the temporary that is the complete object to a subobject of which the temporary is bound persists for the lifetime of the reference except as specified below. **A temporary bound to a reference member in a constructor’s ctor-initializer (12.6.2) persists until the constructor exits**.

Answer (score 2):

Your code involves undefined behavior. The temporary is destructed when the constructor of B exits (C++03, [class.temporary]):

> A temporary bound to a reference member in a constructor’s ctor-initializer (12.6.2) persists until the constructor exits.

Try changing to:

```
B() : a(A()) {
    cout << "B()\n";
};
```

You'll get:

```
A() B() ~A() A ~B()
```